# NoMethodError: undefined method `parent' for #<Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet:0x007fbefee5e420>

Tags: html, css, ruby, nokogiri

I have a problem. I should read a html which contains an image with a class name 'article_img' and I should be able to put it as a sibling of its parent. My code works, but it puts in my test.html both images on the same level with the 'div' instead of putting the other 'img' on the same level with the 'p'

Here is my code:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = File.open('test.html') { |f| Nokogiri::HTML(f)}

doc.css('html').each do |element|
    img = element.css('img.article_img')
    parent = img.first.parent
    parent.before(img)
end
```

and here is my example html

```
<div>       
    <p>Lorem ipsum jne...<a href="#">link</a></p>

    <img class="article_img" src="image.jpg">

    <p>Lorem ipsum jne...<a href="#">link</a>
        <img class="article_img" src="image.png">
    </p>        

</div>
```

Result should be like this:

```
<img class="article_img" src="image.jpg">

<div>       
    <p>Lorem ipsum jne...<a href="#">link</a></p>

    <img class="article_img" src="image.png">

    <p>Lorem ipsum jne...<a href="#">link</a></p>       

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I found an answer:

```
doc.css('html').each do |element|
 images = element.css('img.article_img')
 images.each do |node|
    parent = node.parent
    parent.before(node)
 end
end
```

and shorter version

```
doc.css('html').each do |element|
  element.css('img.article_img').each do |node|
    node.parent.before(node)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd do it:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<html>
  <body>
    <div>       
      <p>Lorem ipsum jne...<a href="#">link</a></p>
      <img class="article_img" src="image.jpg">
      <p>Lorem ipsum jne...<a href="#">link</a>
      <img class="article_img" src="image.png">
      </p>        
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
EOT

img = doc.at('img.article_img')
img.parent.add_previous_sibling(img)
puts doc.to_html

# >> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
# >> <html>
# >>   <body>
# >>     <img class="article_img" src="image.jpg"><div>       
# >>       <p>Lorem ipsum jne...<a href="#">link</a></p>
# >>       
# >>       <p>Lorem ipsum jne...<a href="#">link</a>
# >>       <img class="article_img" src="image.png">
# >>       </p>        
# >>     </div>
# >>   </body>
# >> </html>
```

`doc.at('img.article_img')` finds the first `<img class="article_img"...>`.

We're left with a gap in the HTML because there's a trailing Text node containing the formatting seen in the "pretty HTML". Fixing that is left as an exercise for the reader.